# Невыделение строки в Datagridview при загрузки формы

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Загружаю форму, на ней есть `DataGridView`, которая наполняется данными сразу при загрузки формы.
И всё время выделяется либо первая ячейка, либо первая строка - это зависит от режима в `SelectionMode`.

А можно как-то сделать, чтобы `DataGridView` появился с данными, но чтобы ничего не было выделено ?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте метод [ClearSelection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bxdf3ekh(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
dataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
dataGridView.ClearSelection();
```

Comment: Я использую этот метод, но он работает уже после того, как выведен ДатаГридВью с выделенной 1 строкой.

Я могу нажать кнопку, чтобы убрать выделение 1 строки - и оно убирает.

Но мне нужно, чтобы при первой загрузке ДатаГридВью был без выделения.

Comment: @Владимир, тогда попробуйте повесить выполнение этого кода на событие загрузки DataGridView. Наверно, наиболее близким будет DataBindingComplete

Comment: Спасибо ! Помогло !!